# Call VBA macro by EPPlus

Tags: c#, vba, excel, epplus

I have simple VBA code placed in "F:\Inetpub\wwwroot\webfolder\testWB.xlsm". The macro looks like:

```
Sub TestProcedure()
  MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

How can I call this procedure via C# ExcelPackage?

All what I have is:

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(@"F:\Inetpub\wwwroot\webfolder\testWB.xlsm");
ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);
```

But I haven't found anywhere, how can I call my vba procedure via c# code. I need to use ExcelPackage because Excel.Interop doesn't work on my IIS windows server.

Thanks a lot for any of your advices.

Answer (score 3):

For a concrete answer: from [Epplus WIKI](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/VBA)

> EPPlus supports Creating, Reading and Writing VBA. Execution/Interpretation of VBA code is not supported.

Extracted from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1b608097-afc7-4967-9759-ced2fab4a204/read-vba-macros-or-vbaprojectbin-of-an-excel-file-without-ms-excel-on-server-side?forum=oxmlsdk):

> to execute the VBA code VBE is needed. VBE is installed with Excel.

**So the answer is you can't run VBA Macro from C# without having Excel installed.** There are some workarounds that you may try:

- Replace VBA code for C# code. For example: if your macro puts green backgroud to cells with positive value and red background for negative values, do this programmatically.
- Put your code in Open event so it's automatically run when opening Excel file. This may not work due to Excel security config. (I've read an example somewhere here, at StackOverflow).

Comment: The problem with C# code is you can only see e.g. positive or negative values, on data you create the sheet with, not data entered by a user of the sheet.

Comment: @ProfK For that you can use Conditional formatting. It is supported by EPPLUS: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Conditional-formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Excel calls this procedure when you tell it to do so using "Run macro" or a shortcut. Within the context of EPPlus the macro code is just meaningless text.